# snprintf equivalent for wchar_t to calculate formatted string size (mac)

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Is there any function available to calculate the formatted string size for wchar_t similar to char (snprintf) ?

msvc has snwprintf but I couldnt find an equivalent in mac.

If not is there a way to calculate this with std libraries (without boost)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf#Notes

Comment: From the documentation it returns -1 instead of expected buffer size.
3) Number of wide characters written (not counting the terminating null wide character) if successful or negative value if an encoding error occurred or if the number of characters to be generated was equal or greater than size (including when size is zero)

Comment: From the notes in the wiki there is no wide equivalent and the caller needs to call again with adjusted buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on OSX (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0, clang-800.0.42.1) and CentOS (g++ 4.8.5 20150623 Red Hat 4.8.5-11) using the swprintf() function recommended by Cubbi.

NB the man entry for swprintf() on Mac indicates that its return value is the "number of chars written", not the number of wchars.

I ran the following code, and got the output results shown in the comments on each platform:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

    char narrow_str[] = "z\u00df\u6c34\U0001f34c";

    std::cout << narrow_str << std::endl;                // zß水
    std::cout << strlen(narrow_str) << std::endl;        // 10 (= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4)

    std::wstring wide_str = L"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001f34c";
    std::cout << wide_str.length() << std::endl;         // 4
    std::cout << wcslen(wide_str.c_str()) << std::endl;  // 4

    wchar_t warr[100];

    int n1 = std::swprintf(warr, sizeof warr/sizeof *warr, L"%s", narrow_str);
    int n2 = std::swprintf(warr, sizeof warr/sizeof *warr, L"Converted from UTF-8: '%s'", narrow_str);

    std::cout << n1 << std::endl;                        // 10 with LLVM, 4 with gcc
    std::cout << n2 << std::endl;                        // 34 with LLVM, 28 with gcc
}
```

From this it appears that with LLVM, (1) the original code at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf#Notes) fails and returns -1 because the warr[] array was too small, and (2) the return value from swprintf() is measured in char.

This may, or may not, be helpful.